# How to use React components from local npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm trying to create an npm package with some React components that I use for virtually all of my projects. Here's the folder structure and file contents:

- /

  - dist/

    - bundle.js
  - src/

    - MyComponent.jsx
    - index.js
  - package.json
  - webpack.config.js

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Hello, world!</p>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**index.js**

```
// eventually there will be more components imported/exported here
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.jsx';
exports.MyComponent = MyComponent;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    // some loaders...
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "my-library",
    "files": [
        "dist",
        "src"
    ],
    "main": "dist/bundle.js",
    // the usual stuff...
}
```

This is my understanding of the process. First, I build the src files with webpack. This looks at /src/index.js, imports the MyComponent class, then exports it, making it available as MyComponent. This is all added to a bundle.js file in /dist.

Next, I pack the module with `npm pack`. This creates an archive file with the /src and /dist directories in it.

Then I go over to my other project and run `npm install ../path/to/archive/file`. This adds the module to my node_modules directory. The problem is that when I try to import and use MyComponent...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyComponent from 'my-library';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(<MyComponent />);
        return (
            <MyComponent />
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

...and render that component, I get this warning and error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `App`.

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `App`.
```

The output of the console.log is a React object, but the type is `Object`, which seems like what the warning is alluding to (it should be a string instead, I guess).

Any idea what I'm missing?

---

**EDIT:**

Well, I'm closer. I added library options to my webpack config:

```
output: {
    library: 'my-library',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
}
```

...and then I was able to use the component like this:

```
import MyLibrary from 'my-library';
const MyComponent = MyLibrary.MyComponent;
```

But I don't want to have to do that for every component. My goal is this:

```
import { MyComponent, MyOtherComponent } from 'my-library';
```

Comment: Are you tried with: `import { MyComponent } from 'my-component';` ?

Comment: I tried `import { MyComponent } from 'my-component';` and `const MyComponent = require('my-component').MyComponent;` and got the same warning/error in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your component from the component index.js file like shown below

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.jsx';
import MyOtherComponent from './MyOtherComponent.jsx';
export {
    MyComponent,
    MyOtherComponent
}
```

Then in your Main project, Import them using

```
import { MyComponent, MyOtherComponent } from 'my-library';
```